# How do I calculate number of weeks between two dates using Python?

Tags: python

If I have two dates (ex. '3/1/2016' and '2/28/2017') what is the best way to get the difference measured in weeks?

Comment: 7 days in a week.

Comment: Sorry, should be easy to get out. Just get days between the two dates, and days/7 will be OK.